# Understanding Cassandra, using C/C++ Driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have an application written in C++ that uses the DataStax C++ Driver to communicate with Cassandra.

I run 20 million inserts and then use 50 queries to read those 20 million rows. I have limited my partition key to 50 different possible values so the number of row partitions is a maximum of 50. Also, each query then returns around 300,000 - 400,000 rows.

I am keeping a track of the wall clock time for different parts of this application. The following piece of code that executes the query and gets result takes on an average 3 seconds to complete, which seems reasonable to me.

```
stopWatch.start()
CassFuture* result_future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
if(cass_future_error_code(result_future) == CASS_OK) {
  const CassResult* result = cass_future_get_result(result_future);
}
stopWatch.stop()
```

However, the following piece of code that iterates through the rows takes around 30 seconds on average!

```
resWatch.start();
CassIterator* rows = cass_iterator_from_result(result);

while(cass_iterator_next(rows)) {
     const CassRow* row = cass_iterator_get_row(rows);
     BAEL_LOG_INFO << "got a row " << BAEL_LOG_END;
}
resWatch.stop();
```

I realize that the `CassIterator` could be iterating over some 400,000 rows but is 30 seconds a reasonable time to achieve this?!

Or is there something I'm missing about the way Cassandra functions... does `cass_session_execute()`, `cass_future_get_result()` not fetch all the rows relevant to that query executed and return that to the client? Or does it do it in a lazy manner?

Comment: The Java version of the driver uses paging for results. I would imagine the C++ version does the same. See [Things you should be doing when using Cassandra drivers, item #20](https://ahappyknockoutmouse.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/246/)

Comment: Also described [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0). C++ must have this by now.

Comment: Yeah, see [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/getting-started-with-the-datastax-c-driver).

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I do not run into OutOfMemoery error when results are returned so the results are not that large but I guess they are still large enough that iterating over them takes 30 seconds. Will automatic paging help reduce the iteration time? From the links you suggested it seems like automatic paging is a solution to when the result is too big to fit in memory which is not the case.

Comment: One thing you could have tried is save the data in a file and see how long it takes to transfer that one file over your network connection. Of course, there is overhead with Cassandra since it would send "one file per page" and not one while file at once.